# What are the differences between the Command Dispatcher and Mediator Design Pattern?

Tags: cqrs, mediator

Recently I've been introduced to the Command Dispatcher Pattern which could help the commands to be decoupled from the command handlers in our project that's based on the Domain-Driven Design approach and CQRS pattern.

Anyway, I'm confused it with the Mediator design pattern.

[Robert Harvey has already answered](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/363217/282454) a question about the Command Dispatcher pattern as following:

> A Command Dispatcher is an object that links the Action-Request with
>   the appropriate Action-Handler. It's purpose is to decouple the
>   command operation from the sending and receiving objects so that
>   neither has knowledge of the other.

According to the Wikipedia, [The mediator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) is described as:

> With the mediator pattern, communication between objects is
>   encapsulated within a mediator object. Objects no longer communicate
>   directly with each other, but instead communicate through the
>   mediator. This reduces the dependencies between communicating objects,
>   thereby reducing coupling.

So, as my understanding both of them are separating the command form the commander which allow us to decouple from the caller.

I've seen some projects on Github that are using the Command Dispatcher Pattern to invoke the desired handler for the requested command while the other ones are using mediator pattern to dispatch the messages. (E.g. in most of the DotNet projects, the [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR) library is used to satisfy that).

**However, I'd like to know what are the differences and benefits of using one pattern than another in our project that is based on the DDD approach and CQRS pattern?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mediator pattern is more low level and generic in its pure concept. Mediator pattern does not define the kind of communication or the kind of message you use. In Command Dispatcher you are in a upper layer (contextually and conceptually) in which the kind of communication and message is already defined.

You should be able to implement a Command Dispatcher patter with a Mediator pattern (ergo with MediatR) as foundation.

Answer (score 6):

The Command Dispatcher and Mediator patterns (as well as the Event Aggregator Pattern) share similarities in that they introduce a *mediating* component to decouple direct communication between components.  While each can be used to achieve use cases for which the other pattern was conceived, they are each concrete patterns which differ in their original targeted problems as well as the level to which they are suited for each need.

The Command Dispatcher Pattern is primarily a convention-over-configuration approach typically used for facilitating UI layer calls into an Application Layer using discrete types to handle commands and queries as opposed to a more traditional Application Service design.  When representing the queries and commands that might typically be represented in a course-grained service (e.g. OrderService) as discrete components (e.g. CreateOrderCommand, GetOrderQuery, etc.), this can result in quite a bit of noise in UI-level components such as ASP.Net MVC Controllers where a constructor might otherwise need to inject a series of discrete interfaces, only one of which would typically be needed for each user request (e.g. Controller Action).  Introducing a dispatcher greatly reduces the amount of code needed in implementing components such as ASP.Net MVC Controllers since the only dependency that need be injected is the dispatcher.  While not necessarily a primary motivation of the pattern, it also introduces the ability to uniformly apply other patterns such as Pipes and Filters, and provides a seam where command handler implementations can be determined at run time.  The MediatR library is actually an implementation of this pattern.

The Mediator Pattern concerns the creation of mediating components which encapsulate domain-specific orchestration logic that would otherwise require coupling between components.  That is to say, the mediating component in this case isn't just a dumb dispatcher ("*Hey, anybody know how to handle an XYZRequest?*"), but is purpose-built to follow a specific set of operations that need to occur when a given operation happens, potentially across multiple components.  The example given in the GoF Design Patterns book is a UI component with many interconnected elements such that changes to one need to effect changes to a number of other components and vice-versa (e.g. typing into a text field causes changes to a drop-down and multiple check boxes and radio buttons, while selecting entries within the dropdown effect changes to what's in the text field, check boxes, and radio buttons, etc.).  With the provided solution, a mediating component contains logic to know exactly which components need to get updated, and how, when each of the other components change.

So, the Mediator Pattern would be used when you need a component custom-built to facilitate how a number of other components interact where normal coupling would otherwise negatively affect maintainability whereas the Command Dispatcher Pattern is simply used as a dumb function router to decouple the caller from the called function.

Comment: So, I'm not the sole person in the universe who thinks MediatR is an awful name for the library as it has nothing to do with Mediator the pattern. Knowing this is weirdly comforting :)

Comment: Quick clarification - MediatR is NOT intended to be tied or limited to CQRS, DDD etc. That's why there is no language of "commands" or "queries". You can use MediatR as a command dispatcher, or a query dispatcher, or an event aggregator, but that describes the intent of the requests. I intentionally left intent out. When my colleagues and I first coded the beginnings of MediatR back in 2009 or so, "mediator" was the closest thing we found to describe what we built ‍♂️

Comment: It's an awesome library, regardless of the name.  Love you, Jimmy :)