# What are the differences between the Mediator and Command Design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, mediator, command-pattern

The Mediator and Command design pattern are both Behavioral patterns and describe decoupling a Sender from its Receiver via an intermediate object. In case of the Mediator pattern this intermediate object is called the 'Mediator'. In case of the Command pattern this intermediate object is called the 'Command'. Their difference seems obvious in intent:

- The Command pattern facilitates a function call in the form of an object to gain the advantages of OO.
- The Mediator pattern extracts and centralizes complex object interaction logic.

However, looking more closely to the patterns it seems that the Command pattern is a smaller and more simpler form of a Mediator. My observations:

- The Command pattern is unidirectional, meaning object 1 can send a message to object 2 via a Command object, but not visa versa. A new Command class would be needed to send a message from object 2 to object 1.
- The Mediator pattern is bidirectional, meaning object 1 can send a message to object 2 via the Mediator object and visa versa.

What can be conducted from above observation is that the same goal can be achieved with the Mediator and Command pattern. Only the Command pattern provides messaging in a more distributed way, while the Mediator provides messaging in a more centralized way. This means:

- The Command pattern complies to the Single Responsibility Principle. Each Command contains a single transaction, which has positive affect on the testability, readability and stability of the code. Testability and readability, because the problem window is small. Stability, because the impact of changing a Command is relatively small.
- The Mediator pattern complies to the Single Responsibility Principle, but in a different way. A Mediator contains multiple transactions in a centralized place, that simplifies understanding and extendibility. Understanding, because complex interaction logic between multiple objects can be seen at a glance. Extendibility, because interaction logic can be changed in a single place, by inheriting from the Mediator base.

**Are my observations correct and complete? Do these observations describe when we would prefer one pattern over the other?**

(I viewed the following post: [What are the differences between the Command Dispatcher and Mediator Design Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57963474/what-are-the-differences-between-the-command-dispatcher-and-mediator-design-patt). However, the post didn't fully satisfy the answer that I'm looking for. The answer given in this post doesn't elaborate extensively enough about the differences between the two patterns. On top of that, I'm not quite sure if the 'Command Dispatcher' references to the Command Design pattern.)

Answer (score 0):

A Command is very simple: essentially a single-method interface that takes no arguments. The quintessential examples in Java are [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) and [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html). Any time you use these interfaces or others like them, you're executing Commands.

The power of these "black box" interfaces includes:

- They can be invoked by anyone. Invocation requires no knowledge of parameters.
- They can be invoked any time. Invocation may be eager or lazy.
- They can be invoked any number of times. Invocation may occur zero or more times.

Basically, you can do a lot with a first-class function that doesn't need arguments.

---

Mediator is like a mini enterprise service bus inside your code. It's at a higher level of abstraction than a Command because there's no specific interface for a Mediator. However the colleagues want to communicate, that's the interface the Mediator provides. It could expose different methods for different colleagues.

So there's really nothing in common between these two patterns. A Command has nothing to do with messages. A Mediator has nothing to do with transactions. You could implement either pattern with a Single Responsibility. You could implement either pattern with ten Responsibilities if you wanted to.

Perhaps the most important difference is that Command is a simple, common, and useful pattern (imagine how often those two Java interfaces are used). Mediator tends toward anti-pattern because it almost inevitably becomes a god object.

> The Mediator pattern trades complexity of interaction for complexity in the mediator. Because a mediator encapsulates protocols, it can become more complex than any individual colleague. This can make the mediator itself a monolith that's hard to maintain.  --GoF p.277

Comment: Thanks for the response @jaco0646, I don't fully agree with the statement: 'So there's really nothing in common between these patterns', because Mediator and Command pattern both separate senders and receivers via some intermediate form (i.e. Command or Mediator object). However, using the Mediator for queueing, undoing or redoing interactions, requires much more complexity then doing this via a simple Command object.  As for that, I agree with the part: 'that a Command is a simple, common pattern, because it enables the possibility to easily implement these queue, undoing or redoing features.